# Instance member '....' cannot be used on type 'CustomTextField'; did you mean to use a value of this type instead?

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, programmatically-created

I want to change the 'leftIcon' variable in the CustomTextField class from the ViewController.
however, I get the following error in the CustomTextField class.

**CustomTextField**

```
class CustomTextField: UITextField, UITextFieldDelegate {
    //"person"
    private var showPassword: Bool = false
    var leftIcon: String = ""
    
    private let leftIconView: UIImageView = {
        let icon = UIImage(systemName: leftIcon)
        let imageView = UIImageView(image: icon)
        imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        imageView.tintColor = .white
        return imageView
    }()
}
```

**Error:**

```
Instance member 'leftIcon' cannot be used on type 'CustomTextField'; did you mean to use a value of this type instead?
```

**ViewController**

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    var textfield = CustomTextField()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.textfield.leftIcon = "person"
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry I deleted my answer because it can't possibly be right.  I'm not sure what's going on, but I'll think on it.  The error would make sense if in your `ViewController` the line setting `textfield` were `var textfield = CustomTextField`, without calling the initializer, but you are calling it, so unless there are some other errors that would be relevant, it's kind of a mystery to me.

Comment: So is the error occurring on `let icon = UIImage(systemName: leftIcon) `?

Comment: @ChipJarred yes

Comment: Sorry if you tried reading my answer while I madly edited it.  I got the distilled code to work in Xcode, so I think it will fix your problem when you add back the code I removed.

Comment: I tried both solutions, but I could not change the leftIcon value in CustomTextField from viewDidLoad. @ChipJarred

Comment: Do you get a new error when in `viewDidLoad()`?

Comment: I did not get a new error.

Comment: If you can post the current state of your code, I'll take a look. If not here, maybe in a GitHub gist.

Comment: https://github.com/ufukkosker/CustomTextField 

You have to pod install because I'm using SnapKit.

Comment: OK.  I don't think I need all of the code.  Just an updated version of what you posted here., but all of it is OK too.

Comment: This is demo project no problem. :)

Comment: I'm actually able to compile it with no problem.  Have you tried cleaning your project? (command-shift-K)?  I sometimes get remnants of old errors lingering after they are fixed. That usually solves it but sometimes I have to clean, then quit Xcode, and relaunch.

Comment: The "person" icon on the left side of textfield is not visible. Does this icon appear on you?
I've tried many times but it doesn't work.

Comment: Actually it turns out I was building the wrong target.  I'm getting a log in error of some kind now, so I'm sorting that out.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230682/discussion-between-chip-jarred-and-ufuk-kosker).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I distilled the problem down a bit and recreated it, so you'll want to add back the code I removed.  This code produces the same error:

```swift
class CustomTextField {
    var leftIcon: String = ""
    
    private let leftIconView: UIImageView = {
        let icon = UIImage(systemName: leftIcon) // <--- Error here
        let imageView = UIImageView(image: icon)
        return imageView
    }()
}
```

And tracked down the problem.

The problem is that initializing `leftIconView` is actually happening in a `static` context before the initializer is called, so you can't refer to instance properties.  I found two easy solutions, the first is make `leftIconView` a `lazy var` instead of a `let`:

```swift
class CustomTextField {
    var leftIcon: String = ""
    
    private lazy var leftIconView: UIImageView = {
        let icon = UIImage(systemName: leftIcon)
        let imageView = UIImageView(image: icon)
        return imageView
    }()
}
```

The second solution is to just initialize `leftIconView` in the  initializer.

```swift
class CustomTextField {
    var leftIcon: String = ""
    
    private let leftIconView: UIImageView
    
    override init()
    {
        let icon = UIImage(systemName: leftIcon)
        self.leftIconView = UIImageView(image: icon)
    }
}
```

This second solution will probably require that you also implement some other initializers for `UIView` once you add back that inheritance, and of course you'll need to call `super.init` at the end of the initializer.

#### Addendum

The above solution did indeed fix the compile error, but actually making the icon appear in the `CustomTextField` required using a property observer on `leftIcon`

```swift
class CustomTextField: UITextField, UITextFieldDelegate {
    //"person"
    private var showPassword: Bool = false
    var leftIcon: String = ""
    {
        didSet
        {
            leftIconView = makeImageView(for: leftIcon)

            // leftView is the view that is actually displayed.  It's set
            // once in the initializer, so now that we're updating 
            // leftIconView, we have to update leftView as well
            leftView = leftIconView
            
            // Maybe also do this
            leftView?.setNeedsDisplay()
        }
    }
    
    private lazy var leftIconView: UIImageView = {
        makeImageView(for: leftIcon)
    }()
    
    private func makeImageView(for imageName: String) -> UIImageView {
        let icon = UIImage(systemName: imageName )
        let imageView = UIImageView(image: icon)
        imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        imageView.tintColor = .white
        return imageView
    }
    
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## Alternative Solution

For the cases like yours, alternatively, we can use the static variables too.

```
class CustomTextField {
    static var leftIcon: String = ""
    
    private let leftIconView: UIImageView = {
        let icon = UIImage(systemName: CustomTextField.leftIcon)
        let imageView = UIImageView(image: icon)
        return imageView
    }()
}
```

It's just **much cleaner and shorter**. Except for this call statement:

```
CustomTextField.leftIcon
```